# Change Visual Studio's Default Behavior of Using CLR Type Aliases

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

When implementing an interface, or just about any other "automatic" operation for that matter, Visual Studio defaults to using CLR Type Aliases ("bool" instead of "Boolean".) I have constraints that all variables must be explicitly named (no use of "var") using the explicit CLR Type names. I have found an extremely helpful extension called [Alias Be Gone](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4f18ca8-187b-4f3d-9a1e-eeb8330bb1f7), and it works well. But, I would think Microsoft would have made this an option. Does anyone know where this option might live in the IDE, if it even exists?

Comment: I think that considering they went to the trouble of creating all the aliases in the first place, Microsoft probably prefers that you use them. I personally prefer looking at them.

Comment: Those constraints sound like someone misunderstood the semantics of the aliases and the `var` keyword. What's the intended gain from this?

Comment: I understand and agree FULL-HEARTEDLY with the idea of using aliases. However, my current workplace does not allow it. As for intended gain, there is none. But I am not in the position to change hearts and minds about the issue.

Comment: If you really need to do this, you could probably set up a custom R# inspection, but I think you'd be unlikely to find it native to VS.